# Unticking "Use Shared Runtime" creates performance issues

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've been investigating performance tuning my Xamarin Forms application when running on an Android device using an Intel Atom CPU.

The largest performance I'm currently seeing is when loading a DataTemplate to set as the Content of a ContentView, this DataTemplate then dynamically loads other controls and DataTemplates within it to produce the UI of the application.

Running on this device from the signed APK archive, I am seeing the time taken from tapping on the screen to finish loading the completed UI of 3.9 seconds.

However, if I deploy the application from Visual Studio then run it on the device without the debugger attached, this same process drops to around 1.5 seconds.

It seems to be reliably triggered by the "Use Shared Runtime" option within the project properties.  With this ticked I consistently see this process taking about 1.5 seconds, with it unticked it's up to ~3.9 seconds.  This is the same regardless of application has been built in debug or release mode and regardless of the other settings within the project properties.

This particular scenario is the worst performing part, however I see all UI loading/layout processes improve by a similar ratio, displaying another view drops from 1.5s to 0.8s and so on.

As I am unable to create an archive with this setting ticked, what could be causing this change in performance and how do I get this performance replicated with it unticked?

I am running Xamarin.Forms 3.4.0.1008975, VS2017 15.9.4 and Xamarin.Android 9.1.4.2

Comment: Profile your app as a `Release` configuration as that is your final product. `Shared Runtime` is not something you'd use in `Release` and would be elminated from this equation as it's mostly used for quicker development.

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time

If you are profiling your own UI items, use some logging statements to print out timing.

Comment: I'm aware it wouldn't be used in Release, however enabling it makes a drastic difference to the performance of the application which I'm trying to investigate.  I want to understand what is different between the two and why enabling the shared runtime results in better performance and what I can do to get this with it disabled. It's meant to be something that eases the deployment time rather than give a change in behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having `Use Shared Runtime` ticked selects all architectures in the `Supported Architectures` option in the Advanced window.

Unticking it removes all entries except `armeabi-v7a` meaning `x86` is no longer selected.  As it's now running an ARM application on an x86 CPU it results in the application running slower.

Ensuring `x86` is ticked after unticking `Use Shared Runtime` gives the required performance when running on an x86 based device.